# SQLite3 Is printing more than once PYTHON

Tags: python, printing, sqlite

```
createDb = sqlite3.connect("hh.db")
queryCurs = createDb.cursor()

def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute(''' CREATE TABLE maths
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT, score INTERGER)''')

def addCust(userName,):
    queryCurs.execute("""INSERT INTO maths (userName, score)
    VALUES(?,?)""",(userName, score))

def main():
    #createTable()
    addCust("")
    createDb.commit()

    queryCurs.execute("SELECT * FROM maths")

    title = [userName, class_name,"Score:", score,"Out of 10"]
    k = 0
    for i in queryCurs:
      print ("\n")
      for j in i:
          print (title,[k]),
          print (j)
          if k < 3: k+=1
          else: k = 0

queryCurs.close

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

The Outcome =

```
[<built-in function id>, 'Jack', '10', 'Score:', 0, 'Out of 10'] [0]
5
[<built-in function id>, 'Jack', '10', 'Score:', 0, 'Out of 10'] [1]

[<built-in function id>, 'Jack', '10', 'Score:', 0, 'Out of 10'] [2]
0
```

I want it only once and the ID to be an integer.
Also wanted to know if there is a way i can tidy up the output?

Novice so please explain fully

Answer (score 0):

None of this code is doing what you think it is. You never get anything from the database query - to do so you would have to iterate over `queryCurs.fetchall()`.

The thing you're printing is a list containing some constants you defined previously. And it's looping because you told it to, with `for j in i:`